# Jenkins always building a particular branch before any build

Tags: git, jenkins

Every time we push a a change to our git repository it triggers a build of that branch in Jenkins, however this causes a branch of ours to build before the one we just pushed to.

e.g.

1. Make change to branch `origin/master`
2. Commit and push
3. Jenkins builds branch `origin/release/r40` then builds `origin/master`

We have another Repo and Jenkins Job set up in seemingly the same way that doesn't suffer from this problem. We've tried updating the Jenkins Git plugin but this had no effect.

Comment: There is an option you should be unchecked .... I cannot find it right now, but had the same problem and I have unchecked it and it did not doing it anymore (I'll repost if I find it)

Comment: @sop in the Jenkins configuration?

Comment: sorry, job configuration

Comment: @sop is it "Poll SCM" by any chance?

Comment: Isn't it "Check and mark builds with feature branches"? I am remembering something like "automatic tag", but I don't find it now

Comment: I have found the option that I spoke about: in Source Code Management you have chosen Git, then click on Advanced and there is an option "Skip internal tag", you should check it